# REPLACE query format in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a set of json format stored in a column and now i need to replace a particular word. How to use the replace query. Every time i use it, i'm getting token exception. please advise. Its a DB2 i'm using
I have 3 columns

```
Name    Age   Data
ABD      15   [{"Name":"ABC","type":"Regular","Math":18}]
```

In the Data column, I need to do a replace for "type", It should be StudentType.

```
REPLACE(Data,'type','StudentType');
```

This did not work. How to do it?

Thanks much in advance

Comment: Can you add an example of the token exception? Your usage appears correct: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000843.htm

Comment: [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=replace;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<call>, DRIVER=4.15.82

Comment: For completeness, which platform/version of DB2?  On the iSeries, `SQLCODE = -104` means "not found".  What's your full `UPDATE` statement (or at least the minimum size which reproduces the error)?  As a side note, storing age is problematic, as you have to update it every year (and you don't know when...).

Comment: `REPLACE()` is not a query; it is a function that can be used in an `UPDATE` statement, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Just like @mustaccio pointed out, if you use `REPLACE` in select statement it will just return your data with `'StudentType'` instead of `'type'`. This does not actually change data in your database. If you want to update your data you need `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn,'OldString','NewString')
```

Comment: I would also make your search expression `'"type":'` and your replace expression `'"StudentType":'` this will prevent someone with the text `'type'` in their name or some other property being incorrectly replaced.